# Batch scripting: Why doesn't redirecting stdout work in this scenario?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

If you open up a command prompt and type this:

```
echo foobar > nul
```

it will print nothing, since `nul` swallows all of its input. But if you run the command with PowerShell:

```
powershell "echo foobar" > nul
```

it will output `foobar` to the console. Why is this, and what can I do to fix it?

**edit:** [Here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/016c5b70207a7422b589) is the output of `$PSVersionTable`. It looks like I'm using PowerShell v5.0.

Comment: Works fine in the command-prompt for me in version 3.0.

Comment: What version of Powershell are you using?  I ran your example from a cmd prompt and it ran correctly.  I did not get any output.  I am using version 4.0.

Comment: @rrirower According to `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion`, it looks like I'm using 5.0.

Comment: Can't reproduce: Server 2012 x64/PS 5.0 Preview (5.0.10018.0).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sup>Note: I'm assuming you're invoking your command from *cmd.exe*, not from within PowerShell, which is consistent with the symptoms I'm seeing.</sup>

**Methinks you've stumbled upon a *bug* in PS (PowerShell) v5** (not present in v3; comments on the question suggest it's also not in v4), though I don't fully understand why *PS* is to blame, because I'd expect `cmd.exe` to handle the redirection.
I may be missing something, however, so do let me know.

PowerShell *should* send its so-called success stream - things output by default, including with `echo`, which is an alias of `Write-Output` - to the outside world's *stdout*.

In older PS versions `>NUL` does effectively suppresses PowerShell's output.
Curiously, the **bug in v5  only affects `NUL`, whereas redirecting to an *actual* file works.**

As for **workarounds**:

**If your code is v2-compatible**, try this:

```
powershell -version 2 "echo foobar" > NUL
```

Otherwise, **redirect to an *actual* file and delete that file afterward:**

```
powershell "echo foobar" > "%TEMP%\NUL-bug-workaround" & del "%TEMP%\NUL-bug-workaround"
```

Comment: Thank you! Passing in `-Version 2` seems to have solved the problem. You've just freed me after 2 hours of banging my head on this :D

Comment: PowerShell does not use *stdout*, but [`WriteConsole`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms687401.aspx), when writing to console. So, it need special logic to write to *stdout*, if it was redirected. But, it seems, for some reason, PowerShell does not use `[Console]::IsOutputRedirected`, but use its own logic, flawed for `> nul` case.

Comment: Thanks, @PetSerAl, for pointing out the internals. It's reasonable to expect PS to respect the invoking program's redirections, irrespective of PS's internals, and past PowerShell versions have done so. It sounds that you agree that it's a bug, right? Or was there some intentional change in behavior I'm missing?

Comment: For me, it looks like a bug. I can not think of any reasons for ignoring redirection to `nul`.